# Send emails to posted email address

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Currently, I have a directory website that expiry notices to users. I would like to be able to send these same notices to the registered email address on the directory listings. Currently, the website only sends the email to the post_author.

The directory page looks like:

```
<code>$listing_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true);
  $custom_meta = get_custom_field();
  foreach ($custom_meta as $meta):
  $field = $meta['name'];
  $title = $meta['title'];
  if ($meta['show_on_listing'] == 1) {
  if ($listing_type == 'free' && $meta['show_free'] == 'true') {
  if ($meta['type'] != 'image_uploader' && !in_array($field, $social_exclude)
  ) {
  if (get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true)) {
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td class="label default"><?php echo $title; ?> </td>
  <td><?php
  if ($field == 'geocraft_website') {
  echo '<a target="new" href="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true) . '">' .              get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true) . '</a>';
  } elseif ($field == 'geocraft_phone') {
  echo '<a href=tel:' . str_replace(' ', '', get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true)) . '>' . str_replace(' ', '', get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true)) . '</a>';
  } elseif ($field == 'geocraft_meta_email') {
  echo '<a href=mailto:' . get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true) . '?Subject=subject here&Body=bodytext>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true) . '</a>';
  } elseif ($meta['type'] == 'multicheckbox') {
  echo implode(', ', get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true));
  } else {
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true);
  }
  ?></code>
```

I have the following code for the expiry notice:

```
if ($expire == true && empty($is_expired)) {
$post_author = $listing->post_author;
$site_name = get_option('blogname');
$email = get_option('admin_email');
$website_link = get_option('siteurl');
$listing_title = $listing->post_title;
$lisgint_guid = $listing->guid;
$login_url = site_url("/wp-login.php?action=login");
$listing_user_name = get_the_author_meta('user_login', $post_author);
$message .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
$message .= sprintf(__("Dear %s,", 'geocraft') . " \r", $listing_user_name);
$message .= __("Your listing is expired. We inform you that, if you are interested to reactivate your listing,", 'geocraft') . " \r";
$message .= __("Login in our website and reactivate it.", 'geocraft') . " \r";
$message .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
$message .= sprintf(__("Listing Title: %s", 'geocraft') . " \r", $listing_title);
$message .= "Login On: $login_url \r";
$message .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
$message .= sprintf(__("Website: %s", 'geocraft'), $site_name . "\r");
$message .= sprintf(__("Website URL: %s", 'geocraft'), $website_link . "\r");
$message .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";

//$message1 .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
$message1 .= __("Dear Admin,", 'geocraft') . " \r\r";
$message1 .= __("A listing from one of your users got expired and a notification email has been sent to the user.", 'geocraft') . " \r\r";

$message1 .= __("Expired Listing Details are as follows:", 'geocraft') . " \r";
$message1 .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
$message1 .= sprintf(__("User Name: %s", 'geocraft') . " \r", $listing_user_name);
$message1 .= sprintf(__("Listing Title: %s", 'geocraft') . " \r", $listing_title);
$message1 .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\r";
$message1 .= __("Kindly, Login to your site for more information:", 'geocraft') . " \r\r";
$message1 .= sprintf(__("Login On: %s", 'geocraft'), $login_url . "\r");
$message1 .= sprintf(__("Website: %s", 'geocraft'), $site_name . "\r");
$message1 .= "Website URL: $website_link\r";

//get listing author email
$to = get_the_author_meta('user_email', $post_author);
$subject = __('Your listing reactivation notice', 'geocraft');
$subject1 = __('Expired Listing notification', 'geocraft');
$headers = 'From: Site Admin <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
if (empty($expired_listing)) {
$array = array();
update_option('gc_expired_listing', $array);
}
$expired_listing = (array) get_option('gc_expired_listing');
array_push($expired_listing, $listing->ID);
update_option('gc_expired_listing', $expired_listing);
//email to user
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//email to admin
wp_mail($email, $subject1, $message1);
}
}
```

I know I need to place another wp_mail but I don't know how to define the variable and backward engineer the database PHP variables since I don't have access to it.

```
wp_mail($directoryEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry for the long post. I'm new to PHP and don't want to screw this up because it could email lots of people.

Comment: The website is www.roofingcompaniesomahane.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$listing` is in the format of a WP `$post` object, right after

`$to = get_the_author_meta('user_email', $post_author);`

add

`$to .= ',' get_post_meta($listing->ID, 'geocraft_meta_email', true);`

That way you are sending one email to two people. It would be cleaner to send a total of 3 separate emails, but it's not clear whether or not you have access to the directory listing person's name. You really need database access in order to do this sort of work.

To make sure you don't accidentally email real users, before you make any changes, copy your whole website to a staging/dev site. You can then use phpMyAdmin to change every instance of `geocraft_meta_email` to your own test email address. I like to use Gmail because if you have an address like myname@gmail.com you can actually email myname+anystringyoulike@gmail.com - that way you still receive the actual emails, but it lets you identify exactly which email came through.